# Azure AD, B2B, and Shibboleth Integration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, shibboleth

My organization has our own custom software solution hosted as a Web App in Azure. We are utilizing Azure AD for our authentication security.  Some of our customers may have their own Office365 AD tenants, and so we take advantage of the B2B capabilities to invite these users to our apps and have some visibility of their accounts in our AD tenant (as external users).

We have one customer who would like for us to integrate with their Shibboleth service.  We would like to support using their Shibboleth service as the identity provider for their users, and allow their MFA settings to be honored.  We don't want to force them to create new identities in AD.  What would be needed on our side to support this sort of trusted federation with Shibboleth?  Ideally we'd like to be able to see their identities surfaced as external users in our AD tenant so that we're using a single security model for our app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure AD's only equivalent for "trust" or "federation" with others is, as you've been doing, via B2B. Currently there is no B2B-like equivalent that supports direct federation to non-Azure AD IdPs.

However it is possible to set up Azure AD so that it leverages a third party IdP as its primary auth mechanism.

You should be able combine these two approaches to achieve what you want.

1. Have your customer sign-up for Azure AD
2. Have your customer configure Shibboleth as per the steps in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj205456.aspx
3. Add your customer's users to your Azure AD via B2B as you've been doing for everyone else.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was about to add more into to my post this morning regarding the steps in that Shibboleth integration link which you referenced.  As you point out, the gist of that approach is that the Azure AD tenant setup in that article is owned and managed by the same organization which owns and manages the Shibboleth IdP, correct?  We're looking for an approach which places no extra burden on our customer, other than a typical exchange of certs for a trust relationship.

Comment: @DanSiders, what did you end-up doing to support that scenario?

Comment: Simon, we ended up adding Auth0 (https://auth0.com/) as part of our solution architecture.  Auth0 has SAML IdP support and we were able to integrate with Shibboleth (and other IdPs) this way.  We punted on Azure AD B2B.

Comment: So App -> AzureAD -> Auth0 -> Shibboleth?